# How to exclude null values in queryset for charts.js

Tags: python, django, filtering, exclude-constraint

I am trying to get the count of infringements in the market place for the logged in user.
The logged user is part of a group. The problem I am having is its still counting values for marketplace items that doesn't belong to the group. It adds 0 in the queryset breaking my charts,

```
u = request.user.groups.all()[0].id  
mar_count =  Marketplace.objects.annotate(infringement_count=Count('infringement', filter=Q(groups=u)))
```

The result
'Ebay','Amazon','Facebook','Wallmart', '0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1',

I should be getting
'Ebay','Amazon','Facebook','Wallmart', '1','1','1','1',

How do I exclude counting the marketplace when its no part of the logged in users group? I am new. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the `Marketplace`s, so not in the [**`.annotate(..)`** clause [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
u = request.user.groups.all()[0].id
mar_count = Marketplace.objects.filter(groups=u).annotate(
    infringement_count=Count('infringement')
)
```

The count will always be one (or zero if `ingrigment` is `None`).

One of the problems with your code snippet is that it will always only work with the *first* group of that user, and that can be any of the groups the user is a member of, so it is not very consistent. If you want to count all groups the `user` is a member of, you can use:

```
mar_count = Marketplace.objects.filter(groups__user=request.user).annotate(
    infringement_count=Count('infringement')
)
```

Here the count will always be the number of "matching" groups, or `0` if the `infrigment` is `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you so much, its fixed it. I would appreciated it if you help me solve my other questions.

Comment: @william van onsem I was wondering if you can help me with my other question I posted. Would really appreciate it!